# Packets stuck between two routers

Tags: cisco, subnet

I am trying to send a ping from one subnet to another in cisco packet tracer. The PC sends the packet to the switch, and then to the router of the same subnet via gigabitEthernet (192.168.24.1) and then is sent to the main router of the network on serial connection, from the serial address 192.168.16.1 to the serial on main router 192.168.16.2. The router should then send it to the next subnet, 192.168.24.1, but instead it continiously bounces back between the original subnet router and the main subnet router. Any help with this would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you have a routing loop.  But in order for us to help you, you need to post your switch and router configurations.  A simple diagram would also be helpful.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will almost certainly be found in the routing table of the router that sends the packet in an unexpected direction. In your case that seems to be the "central router".

- Is there a route for the network in question?
- If so does it point to the right interface and nexthop?
- If so are there any other routes with the same or greater specificness that could route the traffic in a different direction.

Assuming you are using static routes I suspect the most likely explanation is that you made a typo when setting up the route.